# java symbolic file link has zero size

Tags: java, file, hyperlink, symlink

I have a program which creates a lot of file-links (just some links, which may point at their real files on the filesystem). These symbolic links have a file size of "0".

What can I do to create a symbolic file link which has a file-size so it is not handled as "empty" file?

**My script searches for empty folders and deletes also the symbolic link files by mistake.**

Is there any best practice to handle this? Or is it better to create a .lnk file (I don't know how...)?

Answer (score 0):

You could either

a) change the file system by downloading the source and building your own version of the kernel.

b) only delete empty files which are not symbolic links.

Comment: I like the sound of option a) - could you show some code for how to do it?

Comment: @Bohemian sure , just uploading it all now. Shouldn't crash SO. ;)